# django import excel file with multi sheets

Tags: python, django, excel, tablib

hello everyone please I have a concern for using Django’s Tablib module to load an excel file that contains multiple sheets. I don’t know how to retrieve a specific sheet

Comment: and what did you do so far? please share with us your workout, code snippet, error logs and any useful information.  Good luck 

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.